# Ellipse through TouchMoved?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

is it possible to draw Ellipse through UITouchMoved in iphone sdk as we do in MSPaint?Any
example please?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you mean ellipse rather than eclipse? If so, use +[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:].

Answer (score 0):

Just save the rect in the touch moved delegate, and draw an ellipse in the rect (maybe using CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect) whenever the view's drawRect gets called.  Call setNeedsDisplay to say that the drawRect needs to be called sometime before returning to the run loop.